# Couchbase Lite in fatjar on heroku throws execption on Couchbase.init()

Tags: heroku, jar, couchbase, couchbase-lite, fatjar

I am facing a problem which only occurs after uploading and executing my jar on heroku. Simply locally it works but online on heroku on execution the application immediately fails because of the Couchbase.init() command which throws (only on heroku) the following exception. What is the real reason behind it, can I fix it or is there any workaround?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYO7n.png)

Comment: What is your smallest project/code which can reproduce the issue? And then share (if possible) the code with us. Probably in the process to shrink the reproducer you might narrow down the problem and find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchbaseLite for Java and Android are bindings for a library written in C/C++

You have built a Jar file that either does not contain the native library, or cannot install it on your system.